# VS 2015 - C# simplify/truncate using namespaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2015, using

I would prefer the following

```
 using Truncating.Long.Using.Namespace.Xxx;
```

Visual Studio 2015, does the following

```
using Xxx;
```

I figured out, that I can change the behavior for the code hint (IDE0001) by adjusting "**Code Analysis**" settings.

But I could not figure out how to STOP the behavior, for the **Ctrl-. inserting a missing namespace**.

Does anyone have some directions or feedback about this?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Why not define a compiler constant? :)

Comment: Wish I could upvote this many, many times.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found an option for this natively in Visual Studio, but the [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) extension provides support for this.  It's been an option [since version 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965291/298754), under [Code Style](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Code_Style.html), called "**Prefer fully qualified using name at nested scope**"